# Can I release a bug fix for an already released ios version? Can I push a new version number before releasing the previous one?

Tags: ios, build, app-store

Longish question for a potentially simple answer, but context might help provide an answer to the question I don't know to ask. :)

We have an app currently available on Android and PC that we are now pushing to ios.  We are struggling to figure out how to make the app store versioning system fit with our existing system.

Our existing version number is of the format xx.yy.zz.  When we start on a new release we increment yy and set zz to 0.  I.e., if our last published version was 3.23.5, then we set the version number to 3.24.0.  For each candidate build that we push to testing we increment the last number (so the next candidate would be 3.24.1).

So certainly we could make the ios version number be xx.yy and the build number zz.

But what happens when we need to push a quick patch for a release because we discover a bug?  For our other platforms that would be, for example, 3.24.2.  Can we release a build for version 3.24 to the app store after that version has already been made publicly available?

Alternately, we could make the version number be the whole xx.yy.zz number, and simply push new version numbers for each testing candidate even though previous versions have not been released.  Is this a no-no?

If neither of these options is possible our trouble is we either have to make some process changes (so build numbers on other platforms bump up to 3.25 on a small patch, which we don't want to do) or we have to make the ios version numbers slightly different.  E.g., 3.24 could be the initial release of a version and 3.24.1 could be the follow up (causing some discrepancy between version numbers across platforms and also some build machine pain since we'll need to detect whether the build is public or not yet).

Note, I have read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

The questions, in case you missed them:

Can we push a new build for a version number that is already on the app store (i.e., a patch of a released version)?

Can we push a build with a new version number when the previous version number is not yet released?  If we did this as a standard practice would Steve Jobs rise from the grave and strangle us (and worse, would Apple ban us)?

Answer (score 0):

iTunesConnct is not that flexible unfortunatlly. To your questions:

Can we push a new build for a version number that is already on the app store (i.e., a patch of a released version)?

> No, once the version is ready for sale you cannot change the binary. You will need to create a new version.

Can we push a build with a new version number when the previous version number is not yet released? If we did this as a standard practice would Steve Jobs rise from the grave and strangle us (and worse, would Apple ban us)?

> Not as far as I know. You will need to release the version in order to upload a new one (with a new version number). You cannot have more than one version pending release. If you try to click on the 'Add version' button while you already have version pending review/release - the button will be disabled. You can do that for different platforms - one build for iOs and one for tvOs.

Hope this helps.